# Can't find error in command line application

Tags: xcode, command-line

Am working on a small command line utility, and have run into error. The error reads

> "Expected identifier or '(' before '='
>   token" in the loop.

Here is the code:

```
    #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    // insert code here...
    int i;

    NSMutableArray *items = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    [items addObject:@"One"];
    [items addObject:@"Two"];
    [items addObject:@"Three"];
    [items insertObject:@"Zero" atIndex:0];
     for (int = 0;i < [items count];i++) {
         NSLog(@"%@", [items objectAtIndex:i]);
     }
    [pool drain];

}
```

Have been trying to find the error, but couldn't. Your help appreciated. TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
 for (int = 0;i < [items count];i++) {
```

to:

```
 for (int i = 0;i < [items count];i++) {
```